# Trouble booting Ubuntu off Chromebook

Tags: ubuntu, boot, chromebook

I followed a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/AxsckwmRhfw) on HP 14 chromebook to replace Chrome OS with Ubuntu. It worked fine for a few boot ups, but when I press Ctrl-L like I normally would to open the BIOS, it just makes a beeping sound.

Comment: there are tons of tutorials on Youtube, please tell us specifically which tutorial you have followed, and with which notebook model.

Comment: I used this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxsckwmRhfw and I used an HP 14 chromebook

Comment: I don't have a substantial answer, but comments on one of links under the video mention this problem, and that it's gonna be pain to fix: https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/comment-page-12/#comment-35997 Seems an HP ChromeBook expert is needed here.

Comment: you may add more specifics to increase chances of getting answer: have you disconnected the battery or let it run out, is there some beeps sequence or it just beeps while you hold the Ctrl+L combo, what it current state (does it boot Ubuntu anyway, or it's stuck at some screen), etc.